# ASP.NET User messages on MasterPages

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i have an admin master page where i want to place a label which i can control with two functions (setErrorMessage and setSuccessMessage) both functions assign strings to label's text property and change CssClass property according to function type.

I want to use these functions from nested pages while the control remains centralized on master page so i can return to form in case of error so user could edit wrong input.

How would you suggest me to do that ? either VB or C#

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below in .aspx

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/Default.master" %>
```

and below in your code behind,

```
this.Master.yourMethod 
this.Master.yourProperty
```

to access your controls in child page.

Answer (score 1):

you must convert type of Master property in nested page:

```
((MyMasterPage)this.Master).lblMessage.Text = "Hi.";
```

Comment: cool but how do i control this from external class which logs errors ? Should i pass Page object to it or extend Page class ?

Comment: Master property is member of Page object of nested page, so if you can access to Page object, you can also get MasterPage object.